# Can't access codeblocks website

Tags: debian, codeblocks

I wanted to change to the IDE codeblock as editor for c++, but i can't access to the website `http://www.codeblocks.org/` even though i tried so from different computers. Is codeblock being maintained furthur an why their website isn't accessable?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeblocks.org/ it's down for me also, as of now.

When in doubt you can always use the site http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ that will check whether it's down for everyone, or just you.